# Using MongoDB upsert in Lithium

Tags: mongodb, lithium

I'm having a bit of a problem performing an upsert in Lithium with MongoDB.  The update works fine but it won't do the insert.  My code is:

```
Feeds::update(
    array('data' =>
        array('user_id' => 
            array('$addToSet' => $user["_id"]) 
        )
    ), //what to change
    array('conditions' => 
        array('address' => $address)
    ), //where to change it
    array('upsert' => true)
);
```

Which should correspond to the MongoDB query:

```
db.osmblags.update( { "address" : "test address" }, { $addToSet : { "user_id" : "56" } }, { upsert : true } );
```

Neither query nor PHP code is working. Is their an alternative to $addToSet that won't allow duplicates in the array of user_ids?

(Sorry I'm new to both Lithium and Mongo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seem to be problems with the first two arguments to `update()`.  Those arguments are for the data and conditions, so you don't need those keys in the arrays you are passing.  Try this.

```
Feeds::update(
    array('$addToSet' => 
        array('user_id' => $user["_id"]) 
    ), //what to change
    array('address' => $address), //where to change it
    array('upsert' => true)
);
```

I'm not sure why the query doesn't work for you directly in MongoDB.  That works fine for me.